# How can I set src and alt attributes on an image tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

JavaScript is something that I am learning bit by bit, so please excuse my ignorance...!

I have a list of images in a gallery, and I am creating a modal on a click event. I have managed to collect all of the sources for the images into an array and have then used the forEach method to appended an li and img tag into a parent ul, with all of the sources going into the src attribute.

My problem is I also have an array of alt attributes as well that I also need to set into the same list of images.

I don't think I can do both attributes in one forEach loop, and it seems too messy to do a second loop for the alt attributes. There must be a simpler way, it's just beyond my current understanding.

Here is the code I already have below, I was wondering if perhaps I should be looking at a JSON object instead rather than this approach?

```
 $('.gallery-image img').click(function(){
            $('.modal').addClass('show');
            var images = document.getElementsByClassName('aurora-gallery-image');
            var imageSources = [];
            var imageTitles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                 imageSources.push(images[i].src);
                 imageTitles.push(images[i].alt);
            }
           imageSources.forEach(imageFunction);
            
            function imageFunction(item){
               $('.image-modal ul').append('<li class="image-modal-item"><img class="modal-content" alt="" src="' + item + '" /><p id="aurora-gallery-image-title">  </p></li>');
            }
           
           
      });
```

Comment: There's no need for 2 loops. Put the `$('.image-modal ul').append(...)` code in the for loop.

Comment: The "alt" attribute is **not** for titles. It is for text that should appear in situations when the image is not available. The "title" attribute is where the title should go.

Comment: Hi Pointy, in the gallery you can type in text to display as a title below the image, it also fires the same text into the alt attribute of the image that is displayed as the thumbnail on the same page, which is where I am collecting it from to display in the modal. Again, as you have pointed out there is  a better way to do this and use the title as well. So I will look at that too. Cheers for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` passes the array index as the second argument to the callback function. You can use that to get the corresponding element from the `imageTitles` array

```
function imageFunction(item, index){
  $('.image-modal ul').append(`<li class="image-modal-item"><img class="modal-content" alt="${imageTitles[i]}" src="${item}" /><p id="aurora-gallery-image-title">  </p></li>`);
}
```

But you don't really need the arrays at all. Just do it in the `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  $('.image-modal ul').append(`<li class="image-modal-item"><img class="modal-content" alt="${images[i].alt}" src="${images[i].src}" /><p id="aurora-gallery-image-title">  </p></li>`);
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, that's perfect thank you, the second version in the for loop is the best option. Love learning all this stuff thanks for the input.